# Pyspark read all JSON files from a subdirectory of S3 bucket

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to read JSON files from a subdirectory called `world` from a S3 bucket named `hello`. When I list all the objects of that directory using boto3, I can see several part files(which were possibly created by a spark job) like below.

```
world/
world/_SUCCESS
world/part-r-00000-....json
world/part-r-00001-....json
world/part-r-00002-....json
world/part-r-00003-....json
world/part-r-00004-....json
world/part-r-00005-....json
world/part-r-00006-....json
world/part-r-00007-....json
```

I have written the following code to read all these files.

```
spark_session = SparkSession
            .builder
            .config(
            conf=SparkConf().setAll(spark_config).setAppName(app_name)
        ).getOrCreate()
hadoop_conf = spark_session._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.server-side-encryption-algorithm", "AES256")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "my-aws-access-key")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "my-aws-secret-key")
hadoop_conf.set("com.amazonaws.services.s3a.enableV4", "true")

df = spark_session.read.json("s3a://hello/world/")
```

and getting the following error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o98.json.
: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: , AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: 
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:976)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:956)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:892)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1426)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:557)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:392)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I have tried with `"s3a://hello/world/*"` and `"s3a://hello/world/*.json"`as well but still getting the same error.

FYI, I am using the following versions of the tools:

```
pyspark 2.4.5
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.1
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

it seems that  the credentials you are using to access the bucket/ folder doesn't have required access right .

Please check the following things

1. Credentials or role specified in your application code
2. Policy attached to the Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2)
   instance profile role
3. Amazon S3 VPC endpoint policy
4. Amazon S3 source and destination bucket policies

Few things which you can use to debug quickly
on your master node of the cluster try to access the bucket using

```
aws s3 ls s3://hello/world/
```

if this throws the error try to resolve the access control by following this link
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-s3-403-access-denied/

Comment: What about s3 access control and vpc  , are you running a emr cluster ?

Comment: No, from my local machine.

Comment: I think it's associated with the access , and vpc  policy